# Tic Tac Toe Command Line

Tags: objective-c

I've coded a 2-Player TicTacToe game using command line.  Code works when player 1 wins in 3 moves, however after player 1 makes their 3rd mark, the game ends saying that "Player 1 wins" even if they haven't won.  I'm new to coding so I know its not the prettiest or shortest way to do this.

```
NSInteger chosen = 0;
NSInteger player = 1;
NSInteger winner = 0;
NSInteger row = 0;
NSInteger column = 0;

NSInteger arr[4][4] = {{0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0}};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //display new board
    NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[1][1], arr[1][2],arr[1][3]);
    NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[2][1], arr[2][2],arr[2][3]);
    NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[3][1], arr[3][2],arr[3][3]);

    do
    {
        if (player == 1)
            {

            //player 1's input
            NSLog(@"Player 1, please choose a cell.");
            NSLog(@"Enter row number(1, 2, or 3).");
            scanf("%ld", &row);
            NSLog(@"Enter column number(1, 2, or 3).");
            scanf("%ld", &column);

            //add input to board
            arr [row][column] = 1;

            //display updated board
            NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[1][1], arr[1][2],arr[1][3]);
            NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[2][1], arr[2][2],arr[2][3]);
            NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[3][1], arr[3][2],arr[3][3]);

            chosen++;

            //check for winner
            if ((arr[1][1] && arr[2][1] && arr[3][1]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if ((arr[1][2] && arr[2][2] && arr[3][2]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if ((arr[1][3] && arr[2][3] && arr[3][3]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if ((arr[1][1] && arr[1][2] && arr[1][3]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if ((arr[2][1] && arr[2][2] && arr[2][3]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if ((arr[3][1] && arr[3][2] && arr[3][3]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if ((arr[3][1] && arr[2][2] && arr[1][3]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if ((arr[1][1] && arr[2][2] && arr[3][3]) == 1) {
                winner = 1;
            } else player++;
            }

        if (player == 2)
            {

            //player 2's input
            NSLog(@"Player 2, please choose a cell.");
            NSLog(@"Enter row number(1, 2, or 3).");
            scanf("%ld", &row);
            NSLog(@"Enter column number(1, 2, or 3).");
            scanf("%ld", &column);

            //add input to board
            arr [row][column] = 2;

            //display updated board
            NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[1][1], arr[1][2],arr[1][3]);
            NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[2][1], arr[2][2],arr[2][3]);
            NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld ",arr[3][1], arr[3][2],arr[3][3]);

            //add a
            chosen++;

            if ((arr[1][1] && arr[2][1] && arr[3][1]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if ((arr[1][2] && arr[2][2] && arr[3][2]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if ((arr[1][3] && arr[2][3] && arr[3][3]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if ((arr[1][1] && arr[1][2] && arr[1][3]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if ((arr[2][1] && arr[2][2] && arr[2][3]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if ((arr[3][1] && arr[3][2] && arr[3][3]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if ((arr[3][1] && arr[2][2] && arr[1][3]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if ((arr[1][1] && arr[2][2] && arr[3][3]) == 2) {
                winner = 2;
            } else player--;
        }

        //player 1 wins
        if (winner == 1) {
            NSLog(@"Player 1 won");
            return 0;
        }

        //player 2 wins
        if (winner == 2) {
            NSLog(@"Player 2 won");
            return 0;
        }

     } while (chosen < 9);

        //no winner

            NSLog(@"Draw");

            return 0;


}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use arrays if you use constant indexes. Learn to use for loops and variable indexes.

Comment: stark, feel free to give examples.  I'm new and willing to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your comparisons are wrong. Instead of

```
if ((arr[1][1] && arr[2][2] && arr[3][3]) == 1)
```

Do

```
if (arr[1][1]==1 && arr[2][2]==1 && arr[3][3] == 1) {
```

For player 1. For player 2, use `==2` instead of `==1`.

Because `arr[1][1]` by itself will be true if the value is not zero...

As it is, since `true` is usually represented as `1`, your condition will say player 1 wins whenever there are three tokens in a row (regardless of what they are).

Comment: PS there are all kinds of things going on in your code that I am itching to comment on, but let's just focus on the reason your code is failing for the moment...

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I'm open to constructive criticism...just be easy...I'm new